# Batch file to open multiple cmd prompts

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm trying to write a batch file that will automate the following manual process:

1. Open a new cmd prompt (prompt1)
2. Run a bat file (b1)
3. Run a program (that will continue to run)
4. Minimize prompt1
5. Open a new cmd prompt (prompt2)
6. Run a bat file (b1)
7. Run a different program (that will continue to run)
8. Minimize prompt2

I've found ways to open multiple instances of cmd to run different things, but after I've run the first thing (b1), I then need to run a program in that same cmd window.

I currently have:

```
start /min cmd /k C:\Users\db2admin\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
start /min cmd /k C:\Users\db2admin\python_environment\Scripts\activate.bat
```

This opens the two windows and runs the bat file; great, but now I need to execute another command (running a python file) in each of the cmd windows. How do I send commands to each prompt?

Comment: So far this is a great list of what you want, but not a good question. :)  What have you come up with already?  Where are you getting stuck?  What have you tried already?

Comment: Literally have done nothing as I've never done batch scripting before. This is a process I currently do manually and want to give a one-click runnable to someone else so they don't have to do this process.

Comment: Well we're not really here to write free scripts _for_ you.  We're here to help with, and offer suggestions for, problems you run into while doing things. :)  Perhaps check out the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) rooms, you may be able to find someone in there willing to consult with you on this at their regular fees.

Comment: @studiohack Why was my answer deleted?

Comment: @techie007 see edit.

Answer (score 13):

Try using this

```
start /min cmd /c batch1.bat && start program1.exe
start /min cmd /c batch2.bat && start program2.exe
```

Comment: @johnharris85 Maybe accept this answer? As it is the only one, and has helped several people.